# Inheriting implicitNotFound messages in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

In Scala, thanks to the `annotation.implicitNotFound` annotation, we can customise the compiler's error message when an implicit is not found.

Is there a way for derived classes to somehow inherit this `implicitNotFound` error message? I.e., something like this:

```
scala> import annotation.implicitNotFound
import annotation.implicitNotFound

scala> @implicitNotFound("custom message") trait Base[T]
defined trait Base

scala> trait Derived[T] extends Base[T]
defined trait Derived

scala> implicitly[Base[Int]]
<console>:13: error: custom message 
       implicitly[Base[Int]]  // my message above, cool
                 ^

scala> implicitly[Derived[Int]]
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Derived[Int]
       implicitly[Derived[Int]]  // not my message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: looks like this is not a supported feature.